# The OptionsResolver component and extra options

Tags: symfony

I have an array which can have various keys. However, always exists two keys which are required. I use the OptionsResolver component now. It is works fine until there is no any extra keys. I also considered the Validator component and as I understood there is the same behaviour. So I need always set the full list of keys but as I wrote above I need validate only some of them. Is there a way to solve this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello you can define required, optional and defaults values in OptionResolver.
Maybe I will give you some example so it will be easier than describing it:

```
$resolver = new Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
$resolver
    ->setRequired(['required1', 'required2'])
    ->setOptional(['optional1', 'optional2'])
    ->setDefaults(['defaultValue' => '123'])
;

$options = $resolver->resolve(
   [
    'required1' => 'test',
    'required2' => 'test123',
    'optional1' => 'opt'
   ]
);
```

then options will be looks like that

```
[
  'defaultValue' => '123',
  'required1' => 'test',
  'required2' => 'test123',
  'optional1' => 'opt',
]
```

if we do not set `required1` or `required2` in resolved array then we got`Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\Exception\MissingOptionsException` exception.
If we give not know option (not defined in setRequired, setOptional or setDefaults) then we got `Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\Exception\InvalidOptionsException` exception.

> I also considered the Validator component and as I understood there is the same behaviour

You can decide which values should be "required"... but not sure if I got what you mean exactly

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Maybe I incorrect wrote. The fact is that I cannot know ahead of optional keys. Thus I will get the exception about which you wrote above.

Comment: Yeah... so I think you cannot do that with OptionsResolver, or I do not know how ;) I think that you need to define all optional options using setOptional method first. About validation component you can create custom validators and make own logic there so it should not be the problem.

Comment: I am leaning towards the Validator component. However, I have already use the OptionsResolver for one piece of the code where it works great. I think use of them both is not a good idea. Am I right?

Comment: Looks like I found the solution. I will use the `allowExtraFields` options for collection constraint in the Validator component.